# Asterisk on jupyter(python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was making code on python but it showed an asterisk where the number goes on the cell, I tried making a print program to see if it was the code but it still didn't work. Please help, this is the code.

```
Items = ""
Total = 0
def adding_report(report):
    while True:
        X = input("please input integer to add or Q to quit")
        if X.isdigit() == "True":
            X = int(X)
            Total = Total + X
            if report == "A":
                Items = Items + X
        elif X == "Q":
            print("Your result is")
            if report == "A":
                print("Items")
                print(Items)
            print("total")
            print(Total)
            break
        else:
            print("invalid input.")
adding_report("T")
```

Comment: what is the error?, what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You are stuck in an infinite loop.
Moreover, you cannot compare to the **string** `"True"`, but rather to `True` only:

```
if X.isdigit() == True:
```

Instead of:

```
if X.isdigit() == "True":
```

You can also skip the comparison to `True` altogether

```
if X.isdigit():
```